# SVG: getting a precise bounding box of a path?

Tags: javascript, browser, svg

The `SVGPath.getBBox()` implementation in at least WebKit seems somewhat shoddy; is there some better (cheaper) way than walking the path (or sampling it over and over at random), manually computing its probable bounding box, to get a good reading?

http://bl.ocks.org/2939938 (or https://gist.github.com/2939938) shows an example of the latter and when I run it in a few different fairly modern browsers, there is notable variation in the native implementation. Opera is best, Firefox good and Chrome / Safari ocular-notably bad:

```
616.1572 677.0540 127.6856 126.8793 - sampled, gathering random coords for 5s (reference)
616.1569 677.0538 127.6860 126.8796 - opera 11.64 build 1403
616.1563 677.0547 127.6875 126.8789 - firefox aurora 15.0a2 (2012-06-15)
614.2805 673.9761 136.2089 129.9573 - chrome canary 21.0.1176.0
614.2805 673.9761 136.2089 129.9573 - safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)
```

Or, left/top/width/height variation from the reference bounding box in percent:

```
0.00005% 0.00003% 0.00031% 0.00024% - opera
0.00015% 0.00010% 0.00149% 0.00032% - firefox
0.30458% 0.45460% 6.67522% 2.42593% - chrome
0.30458% 0.45460% 6.67522% 2.42593% - safari
```

Comment: If you specify what you want to use the bounding box for, and what sort of paths you are analyzing, that might help us suggest appropriate solutions or better approximations.

Comment: My main interest at the moment is deriving exact `viewBox` attributes for single-path-element SVG:s, as in the linked example, that fit the graphic perfectly, making it scale with no cropping or extra padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) implements a rather excellent [Raphael.pathBBox](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.pathBBox), for the case where you have a `<path>` element specifically; it seems algebraically exact, and is fast. Added to the comparison test page.

Comment: According to the code you linked in your question, Firefox's native getBBox is now just as precise as Raphael's, though Chrome is still a few pixels off.